# How to get date range using moment.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

This is my html page

```
<tr ng-show="option == 'Yearly' || option == 'Date'">
            <td>
                <label>From:</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" ng-model="fromdate" id="from" date-picker date-type="from" month-directive />
                {{fromdate}}
            </td>

            <td>
                <label>To:</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input id="todate" type="text" ng-model="todate" date-picker date-type="to" month-directive />
                {{todate}}
            </td>

        </tr>
```

This is my directive

```
app.directive('monthDirective', function () {

return {

    restrict:'A',
    link: function (scope, elem) {
        var fromDate, toDate;
        scope.$watch('fromdate', function (newValue, oldValue) {
            fromDate = newValue;
            console.log('fromDate', newValue);
        });
        scope.$watch('todate', function (newValue, oldValue) {
            todate = newValue;
            console.log('todate', newValue);
        });

        var range = moment().range(fromDate, toDate);
        var diff = moment.preciseDiff(fromDate,toDate);
        console.log('Range', range);
        console.log('diff', diff);
    }
}
```

})

I need to get the range between fromdate and todate using mument.js. Can anyone suggest how to do this in my scenario. Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you using `moment range` extension?

Comment: Do you want to get the difference in days ?

Comment: Not sure what this has to do with Angular....

Comment: What is the expected result and where do you plan to use it?

Comment: I need to know what are the dates between 'fromdate' and 'todate'

Answer (score 17, accepted):

To get rest of the dates between two dates, you can refer this code-

```
$scope.dateArr = []; //Array where rest of the dates will be stored

$scope.prevDate = moment().subtract(15, 'days');//15 days back date from today(This is the from date)

$scope.nextDate = moment().add(15, 'days');//Date after 15 days from today (This is the end date)

//extracting date from objects in MM-DD-YYYY format
$scope.prevDate = moment($scope.prevDate._d).format('MM-DD-YYYY');
$scope.nextDate = moment($scope.nextDate._d).format('MM-DD-YYYY');

//creating JS date objects
var start = new Date($scope.prevDate);
var end = new Date($scope.nextDate);

//Logic for getting rest of the dates between two dates("FromDate" to "EndDate")
while(start < end){
   $scope.dateArr.push(moment(start).format('ddd DD-MM'));
   var newDate = start.setDate(start.getDate() + 1);
   start = new Date(newDate);  
}

console.log('Dates:- ');
console.log($scope.dateArr);
```

This is the console log:-

> ["Tue 24-05", "Wed 25-05", "Thu 26-05", "Fri 27-05", "Sat 28-05", "Sun
>   29-05", "Mon 30-05", "Tue 31-05", "Wed 01-06", "Thu 02-06", "Fri
>   03-06", "Sat 04-06", "Sun 05-06", "Mon 06-06", "Tue 07-06", "Wed
>   08-06", "Thu 09-06", "Fri 10-06", "Sat 11-06", "Sun 12-06", "Mon
>   13-06", "Tue 14-06", "Wed 15-06", "Thu 16-06", "Fri 17-06", "Sat
>   18-06", "Sun 19-06", "Mon 20-06", "Tue 21-06", "Wed 22-06"]

Comment: I want to know what are the dates between 'fromdate' and 'todate'

Comment: @SamDaniel I have edited the code. let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Oh my god, so much code on one-liner function and this one is the best answer? Check my answer better

Answer (score 23):

I know this is an old/answered question, but since it's at the top of google here is how to achieve a date range with only `moment` (and without `moment-range`):

```
import moment from 'moment'

/**
 * @param {date|moment} start The start date
 * @param {date|moment} end The end date
 * @param {string} type The range type. eg: 'days', 'hours' etc
 */
function getRange(startDate, endDate, type) {
  let fromDate = moment(startDate)
  let toDate = moment(endDate)
  let diff = toDate.diff(fromDate, type)
  let range = []
  for (let i = 0; i < diff; i++) {
    range.push(moment(startDate).add(i, type))
  }
  return range
}
```

Returns an array of every "type" (month/day/hour etc) between the two, exclusive of the end date

Example:

```
let range = getRange('2019-01-01', '2019-01-05', 'days')
// moment dates -> [ '2019-01-01', '2019-01-02', '2019-01-03', '2019-01-04' ]
```

Comment: The last date is missing in the range

Comment: use `i <= diff` instead to get the last day :)

Comment: As long as you already have size of array (```diff```) better to initialize array with known capacity: ```let range = new Array(diff)```

Answer (score 5):

You can do something like this to get the difference in days:

```
var fromDate = moment();
var toDate = moment().add(15, 'days');

var range = moment().range(fromDate, toDate);
var diff = range.diff('days');

var array = range.toArray('days');
$.each(array, function(i, e) {
  $(".container").append("<li>" + moment(e).format("DD MM YYYY") + "</li>");
});

console.log('Range', range);
console.log('diff', diff);
```

**EDIT**

I added a little example for the `toArray` function :

https://jsfiddle.net/Tintin37/19n5ykzs/

Comment: I want to know what are the dates between fromdate and todate

Comment: You can use toArray so, like this `range.toArray('days');` You ll get an array of dates, each item of the array ll be a date between your stardate and enddate

Comment: I am getting an error that toArray is not a function. Any suggestions?

Comment: Still the same error , I have updated the fiddle with my code, Kindly Check and let me know were I am wrong        https://jsfiddle.net/19n5ykzs/1/

Comment: It should be something like this https://jsfiddle.net/Tintin37/6tdgsbh5/. Have a great day

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114012/discussion-between-sam-daniel-and-quentin-roger).

Comment: i will just add the `.toArray()` is removed in v3 and replaced by some other functions like Array.from(range.by('days'))`
see here: https://github.com/rotaready/moment-range/issues/111#issuecomment-265642435

Comment: just for record method `range` is a separate MomentJs plugin. To instal it `npm install moment-range` and then `npm install moment-range` and add to the code `const Moment = require('moment'), MomentRange = require('moment-range'), moment = MomentRange.extendMoment(Moment);`

Answer (score 5):

```
const getDaysRange = (date1, date2) => {
  if (date1 && date2) {
    return Math.abs(moment(date2).diff(moment(date1), 'days')) + 1;
  }

  return undefined;
};
```

Comment: It would be better if you provide an explanation to why your code works.

Comment: the code is simplest as possible, what explanation do you need?

Comment: It doesn't even work. It just gets the count of days. Not the range.

Comment: @zola25 for me count of days between two dates = range, author don't specify what exactly he wants

Answer (score 3):

If you want to get consecutive days between two dates:

1. Install MomentJS and MomentRange: `npm i moment && npm i moment-range`
2. Some code

```
const 
   Moment = require("moment"),
   MomentRange = require("moment-range"), 
   moment = MomentRange.extendMoment(Moment); /*add plugin to moment instance*/ 

let 
   range = moment().range("2018-02-20", "2018-03-01"), /*can handle leap year*/ 
   array = Array.from(range.by("days")); /*days, hours, years, etc.*/ 

array.map(m => {
     console.log(m.format("YYYY-MM-DD")); /*or any format you like*/
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To get **range of dates in the array**, you can try my not perfect and not optimized function below.

Case description:

There are two dates:

**1) 01.01.2023**

**2) 31.01.2023**

Expected result:

**const resultArr = [01.01.2023,
02.01.2023,
03.01.2023,
04.01.2023,
05.01.2023,
...,
31.01.2023]**

**Solution with using moment.js library**:

```
/**
 * @name getRangeDatesBetweenTwoDates
 * @param _minDate {Moment}
 * @param _maxDate {Moment}
 * @param _format {string}
 * @param _currentDate {Moment}
 * @returns {*[]|*}
 */

export const getRangeDatesBetweenTwoDates = (
  _minDate,
  _maxDate,
  _format = dateFormat,
  _currentDate,
) => {
  const rangeDates = [];

  const getDatesRecursively = (
    minDate,
    maxDate,
    format = dateFormat,
    currentDate,
  ) => {
    const minDateStart = moment(
      minDate.startOf('day').format(serverDateFormat),
      serverDateFormat,
    );
    const maxDateStart = moment(
      maxDate.startOf('day').format(serverDateFormat),
      serverDateFormat,
    );

    if (
      minDateStart.isAfter(maxDateStart) ||
      !minDate ||
      !maxDate ||
      !currentDate
    )
      return;

    if (currentDate.isSame(maxDateStart)) {
      rangeDates.push(currentDate.format(dateFormat));

      return rangeDates;
    }

    rangeDates.push(currentDate.format(dateFormat));

    const _nextDay = moment(currentDate)
      .add(1, 'days')
      .format(serverDateFormat);

    return getDatesRecursively(
      minDateStart,
      maxDateStart,
      format,
      moment(_nextDay, serverDateFormat),
    );
  };

  return getDatesRecursively(_minDate, _maxDate, _format, _currentDate);
};
```

**dateRanges** is your resultArr

```
const dateRanges = getRangeDatesBetweenTwoDates(
  moment(01.01.2023, 'DD.MM.YYYY'),
  moment(31.01.2023, 'DD.MM.YYYY'),
  'DD.MM.YYYY',
  moment(01.01.2023, 'DD.MM.YYYY'),
);
```

Recommended to optimize and simplify this function by removing extra moment wrappers