# Obtain the days between the range in the datepicker of jQueryUI

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I'm using the [date range picker](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#date-range) of `jQuery UI` and it's working perfectly. But now I'm thinking maybe is useful  obtain a list of the days between the range. Is this possible?

I did it manually defining what months have 30 and 31 days, February with 28 days and comparing the year of the starting day and the ending day. But I think there has to be a simpler option.

I'm so sorry I don't have code to show because I don't know what function or method I have to use because my code is working but I just think maybe there is a better option. If you think this is a bad question for this page comment it and I delete it immediately.

Comment: please do some research and _googling_ to solve this problem

Comment: Have you checked if moment.js would offer a solution? momentjs.com

Comment: Also this https://stackoverflow.com/a/37673619/3279876

Comment: @NEA, there are no specific functions for getting days between range in javascipt, instead you can use other methods to solve this issue for example making an array and removing the dates that are not between range something like this

Comment: This is a great resource for dates: https://github.com/you-dont-need/You-Dont-Need-Momentjs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with `.setDate()` for a Date Object.

> Expected values are 1-31, but other values are allowed:
>
> - `0` will result in the last day of the previous month
> - `-1` will result in the day before the last day of the previous month
>
> If the month has 31 days:
>
> - `32` will result in the first day of the next month
>
> If the month has 30 days:
>
> - `32` will result in the second day of the next month

Using the difference in the number of days between the two dates, you can iterate and create new Date objects with the set number of days.

```js
$(function() {
  var dateFormat = "mm/dd/yy";

  function getDate(element) {
    var date;
    try {
      date = $.datepicker.parseDate(dateFormat, element.value);
    } catch (error) {
      date = null;
    }

    return date;
  }

  function listDays(dta, dtb) {
    var result = [];
    if (dta == undefined || dtb == undefined) {
      console.log(dta, dtb);
      return [];
    }
    var dayDiff = (dtb - dta) / 86400000;
    var d = dta.getDate();
    var n = new Date(dta.setDate(d));
    for (var i = 0; i <= dayDiff; i++) {
      n = new Date(n.setDate(d));
      d++;
      if (d > 32) {
        d = 2;
      }
      result.push($.datepicker.formatDate(dateFormat, n));
    }
    return result;
  }

  var from = $("#from")
    .datepicker({
      defaultDate: "+1w",
      changeMonth: true,
      numberOfMonths: 3
    })
    .on("change", function() {
      to.datepicker("option", "minDate", getDate(this));
    }),
    to = $("#to").datepicker({
      defaultDate: "+1w",
      changeMonth: true,
      numberOfMonths: 3
    })
    .on("change", function() {
      from.datepicker("option", "maxDate", getDate(this));
      console.log(listDays(getDate(from[0]), getDate(this)));
    });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<label for="from">From</label>
<input type="text" id="from" name="from">
<label for="to">to</label>
<input type="text" id="to" name="to">
```

Comment: Hello, thank you very much for the answer. Can I ask one more question? Is it possible to save all this code in a external js file and call it when I need it? I'm trying it but I don't know how to do it. THANKS!!!

Comment: @NEA yes that is possible.