# Get days using Javascript with Moment.js

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I have this code to get the remaining days of the week:

```js
const getWeekDates = () => {
    let weekDates = [];
    let remain = 7 - moment().day();
    for (let i = 0; i < remain; i++) {
        weekDates.push(moment().add(i, 'd'));
    }
    return weekDates;
};
console.log(getWeekDates());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

My question is:

- How do you get the days for next week?
- How do you get the remaining days of the current month?
- How do you get the days of next month?

Comment: Just so you know: moment.js is now in maintenance mode, you should start using another library. Luxon is from one of moment.js's team, but I would recommend day.js.

Comment: How are you defining "remaining days of the week"? As I try this on sunday evening I get today through to next saturday. Same question applies to all your requirements, ie when does "next week" start?

Comment: [How to get date range using moment.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37673322/how-to-get-date-range-using-moment-js/37673619)

Comment: @Jamiec that's exactly correct, the remaining days of the week will always end on a Saturday if that's what you mean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```js
moment(jso).endOf('month').unix();
```

To get the end of the month, where `jso` here is the day reference.

And to get the first day and last of the next week, something like this should work:

```java
public static native String startOfNextWeek(JavaScriptObject today) /*-{
   return $wnd.moment(today).add(1,'weeks').startOf('week').unix();
}-*/;

public static native String endOfNextWeek(JavaScriptObject today) /*-{
   return $wnd.moment(today).add(1,'weeks').endOf('week').unix();
}-*/;
```

The above code is using [GWT (a Java to JS transpiler)](http://www.gwtproject.org/) but the idea should pretty much show, first get the day today and add 1 week from that and use the `startOf` and `endOf` methods for "week".

Comment: And obviously to get next month it would be something like: `$wnd.moment(today).add(1,'months').startOf('months').unix();`